# addClass and then removeClass the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$(".CSS3-Animation").addClass('on');
```

This apples a set of CSS3 animation lines to the `.CSS3-Animation`.
Now what I'm trying to do is to remove this class name right after it's loaded.

CSS:

```
.CSS3-Animation.on{
    animation:grow 0.5s both 0.3s
    }

@keyframes grow{
    0%{transform:scale(.8);opacity:0}
    100%{transform:scale(1);opacity:1}
}
```

I need to removeClass("on") after the animation is done so the following CSS will work:

```
.CSS3-Animation{
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-duration: 250ms;
}
.CSS3-Animation:hover{
    transform: scale(1.02) translate(0,2px);
}
```

Obviously the below doesn't work:

```
        $(".CSS3-Animation").addClass('on');
        $(".CSS3-Animation").removeClass('on');
```

What are the ways to get around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do this ?

Comment: That does work, at least as far as your question describes. The implication is that you want to remove it after a CSS animation (do you really mean animation? or do you mean transition?) has completed. Is that the case?

Comment: If you know animation duration then remove class after that period of time.

Comment: You need to wait untill the CSS animation has ended before you remove the class.

Comment: @dfsq - It would be better and safer to use the `animationend` event.

Comment: what type of animation is it?

Comment: Thank you, it's updated now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `onwebkitanimationend` like this:

```
$(".CSS3-Animation").addClass('on').on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('on');
});
```

You can chain the event `animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd` after adding the class `on`.

Comment: Thank you, but does it only work in webkit browsers?

Comment: @Nima all the modern browser can use this `animationend` but others which does not have implemented it there browser or still in development then you can use vendor prefixes like`webkit, moz, o` etc.

Comment: Great. I tested it in Mozilla just now too and it works, a bit buggy in Mozilla but works fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `animationend` event:

```
$(".CSS3-Animation").on('oanimationend animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function() { 
   $(".CSS3-Animation").removeClass('on');
});
```

using javascript:

```
 $(".CSS3-Animation")[0].addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", removeclass,false);
 $(".CSS3-Animation")[0].addEventListener("animationend", removeclass,false);
 $(".CSS3-Animation")[0].addEventListener("oanimationend", removeclass,false);
```

**[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend)**